# Call function from another header in C

Tags: c, operating-system

I am writing a small kernel and I need some clarification. I know it is a bad practice to write function definitions in the header files and instead they should be in a compilation unit. Nevertheless, I wrote a `print` function in one header and a `get mmap()`function that gets memory map in another header. When I call the `print` function from `kernel_main()` in kernel.c, it is working as expected. But when I call `print` function from inside `get_mmap()`, it doesn't work and the kernel is getting stuck in an infinite boot loop. I don't know how to debug this and I want someone to explain me what is going wrong at the system level.

Comment: Did you designate it `static inline`?

Comment: No, I didn't mark it static inline

Comment: Do that (be sure to compile as C99 at the very least), and add an edit to your post, whether it didn't work

Comment: If you know that something is bad practice, then simply refrain from doing it. Sigh. In addition to the static inline tip, you should also use header guards.

Comment: `static inline` fixed the problem, thanks a lot @StoryTeller. @Lundin, i was just experimenting around and thanks a lot.

Comment: @StoryTeller, shouldn't the linker complain because it sees two definitions of print? I can see why `static inline` fixed it, but how was it linking in the first place?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - I wouldn't be able to tell you. The fact this is kernel code and probably compiled with a bunch of flags I don't know anything about, may be what caused the linker to goof.

Comment: Yes, makes sense! @rithvikp, could you please share the exact way in which you are compiling the modules? I need to see them for my sanity.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Please find the makefile [here](https://github.com/rithvikp1998/myOS/blob/master/Makefile) and the linker file [here](https://github.com/rithvikp1998/myOS/blob/master/linker.ld) I didn't push the `static inline` change yet. Please inform me if you find any other mistakes. I plan to change the header files soon.

Comment: @rithvikp, where did you try to call the printx function that cause the boot loop? ( I assume that printx is the function that is causing the issue)

Comment: I was trying to use it in `get_mbmmap()` in pmm.h to print base address